# Does SL4FJ provide the equivalent of Log4J PatternLayout?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I currently use Log4J for a library and wanted to move to using SLF4J to allow the user of the library to choose the logging framework.

Everything is fine apart from one class that I use to replace text in the log message before it gets to screen or log:

```
public class FilteringLayout extends PatternLayout {

    private static final String REPLACEMENT = "[APIKEY]";
    private static Pattern replacementPattern = Pattern.compile("DO_NOT_MATCH");

    public static void addReplacementString(String replacementString) {
        replacementPattern = Pattern.compile(replacementString);
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage() instanceof String) {
            String message = event.getRenderedMessage();

            Matcher matcher = replacementPattern.matcher(message);
            if (matcher.find()) {
                String maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll(REPLACEMENT);

                Throwable throwable = event.getThrowableInformation() != null
                        ? event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable() : null;

                LoggingEvent maskedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.fqnOfCategoryClass,
                        LoggerFactory.getLogger(event.getLoggerName()), event.timeStamp,
                        event.getLevel(), maskedMessage, throwable);

                return super.format(maskedEvent);
            }
        }
        return super.format(event);
    }
}
```

How would I do this with pure SLF4J and remove the reliance on Log4J?

EDIT: Just to make it clearer, I want to remove a set sequence of characters from the log message automatically and before it's sent to the downstream logger.

Comment: SLF4J is just a façade, what implantation are you using? You could still code against the SLF4J API and use Log4J to do the actual logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve the same thing using SLF4J's Mapped Diagnostic Context feature. It works with both log4j and logback as backends. See http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html

Quote from [SLF4J's manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

> "Mapped Diagnostic Context" is essentially a map maintained by the logging framework where the application can provided key-value pairs, which can then be inserted by the logging framework in log messages.

#### Edit:

Sorry, I haven't read your code carefully enough. I think SLF4J (being just a logging API) doesn't support filters and functionality like that by default. You could however implement a wrapper that processes the log messages before forwarding them. Extend `LoggerWrapper` and create a corresponding `LoggerFactory` that you could use throughout your codebase. See the sources of `XLoggerFactory` and `XLogger` in `slf4j-ext` as an example.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for.   I don't need to pass anything to the subsequent logger, I want to check each and every line sent to that logger and remove a specific sequence of characters from that log text.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After some more thinking about the "problem" I realised that perhaps the best approach is to leave the log filtering to the end client.